Making wired USB MIDI controller transmit data over Bluetooth
I want to make a USB MIDI controller more practical by passing the data via bluetooth. I'm don't have that much experience with electronics engineering, so I'm coming here ask for advice.
Namely it is Akai MIDImix, it connects via USB 2.0 B type, I would like to use ESP32 to transmit data and power everything with some lithium batteries with charging and protection circuit (maybe scrape from some power bank).
Question1: Is it too naive of a thought that just connecting regular Bluetooth dongle that you normally would connect to a PC and powering that whole USB line with some battery pack would do it? Could this work?
Question2: Design I want to go with is
power : 5V from internal battery+regulator -> USB power pins
data : USB lines -> CP2102 module (get Rx,Tx) -> UART to ESP32 -> succesful wireless data transfer? Is that possible? Or what could be done better, please bear in mind my knowledge in electronics in general is somewhat poor.
Thanks for any advice on this:)

Not going to work, sorry. The latency requirements alone are a non-starter.

How much latency we are talking about? I would be fine with as much as 100ms when plugged wirelessly. It's not that crucial. The source of latency would be communication between ESP32 and reciever? And other than that, could that work?

@vir -- wouldn't that very clearly depend upon what you're using MIDI for??  for that matter, https://thomasgerbrands.medium.com/the-truth-about-bluetooth-midi-54a3dc633052

Also, this is pretty much routinely commercially available: https://www.amazon.com/stores/page/BE398929-5D23-4CDE-956D-1E41CE58BE96?ingress=2&visitId=628da2a3-eb37-4f04-acc2-341a09f16815&store_ref=bl_ast_dp_brandLogo_sto&ref_=ast_bln
